# When parsing YAML file using yaml-cpp, does it 'copy' all child nodes?

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

When parsing yaml file, normally we get root node from parser.

And I'm wondering if I can reference the root node after parsing process. Like below.

```
YAML::Node* globalRoot;

void ParseDocument(filename)
{
  YAML::Parser parser(fin)
  parser.GetNextDocument(*globalRoot);
}

void myFunction()
{
  ParseDocument("myYAML.yml");

  // After the method above, we lose the parser instance since it's a local variable.
  // But if all child data is copied, below code should be safe.
  // If globalRoot is just pointing inside the parser, this could be dangerous.

  std::string stringKey;
  (*globalRoot)["myKey"] >> stringKey;
}
```

Can I use like code above??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does - once a `Node` is parsed, it does not rely on any memory from the `Parser`.

That said, in your example, you never actually construct the node pointed to by `globalRoot`. You'd need to call

```
globalRoot = new YAML::Node;
```

and even better, keep it in a smart pointer like `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: yeah I missed that. Thanks for your answer! I can use it now ;)